# Disabling write caching in a Ubuntu VM to avoid file system corruption?

Tags: filesystem, vmware, ext3

Quite a few times over the years have I had Ubuntu lock-up at some point, and upon starting I have found that the file system has been damaged in some way. I only notice what went wrong when trying to access files during development and getting errors, making me have to clone repos and whatnot all over. I thought journalling was supposed to take care of this, but does not seem so ... For the last few years, Ubuntu has been running in VMWare, and that has worked pretty darn well, but some time ago the VM crashed - again causing file system corruption on the ext3 partition.

This left me wondering: Windows and the device drivers has its own layer of file system caching. Can I disable write caching in Ubuntu without a noticeable performance hit in order to avoid/minimize file system corruption? Running on SSDs and such makes the performance pretty good anyway.

Comment: When you suffer a lock-up, are you cleanly shutting down your system (ie. directing the kernel to sync buffers to disk, umount etc via SysRq commands or the like) or just restarting/shutting it down via the HOST/hardware. If you're not cleanly shutting down the system, a `fsck` I would expect needs to be performed. Unless you're talking kernel panic, you should be able to cleanly shutdown/reboot/etc the system.

Comment: Definitely not shutting it down cleanly. Just asking VMWare to shut it down, possibly forcing a poweroff. Not even sure if SysRq works on VMWare?